# Pandas reads date from CSV incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am very new to Python, and finding it very frustrating.
I have a CSV that I am importing, but its reading the date column incorrectly.
In the Month column, I have the 1st of each month - so it should read (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
2020-01-01
2020-02-01
2020-03-01
etc
```

however, its reading it as (yyyy-dd-mm)

```
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
etc
```

I've tried several conversion functions from stackoverflow as well as other websites, but they either just don't work, or do nothing.

My import is as follows:

```
try:
    collections_data = pd.read_csv('./monthly_collections.csv')
    print("Collections Data imported successfully.")
except error as e:
    print("Error importing Collections Data!")
```

[image]

I have tried the `parse_dates` parameter on the import, but it doesn't help.

If I then try this:

```
temp = pd.to_datetime(collections_data['Collections Month'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
temp
```

then I get

[image]

which you can see, it is reading the months as the days - in other words, it is showing individual days of the month, instead of the 1st day of each month.

I'd greatly appreciate some help to get these dates corrected, as I need to do some date calculations on them, and also join two tables based on this date - which is going to be my next problem.

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried that hasn't worked when reading in from csv

Comment: Use `dayfirst = True` kwarg of `pd.read_csv()`. The default behaviour is to assume dates are in month first format for ambiguous dates. In your attempt using `pd.to_datetime()` you've used `format='%m/%d/%Y'` which is explicitly saying your dates are in a month first format, if you switch the position of `%m` and `%d` that would also work.

Answer (score 1):

### Inferring date format

Some dates are ambiguous, while others aren't. Consider these dates:

1. 2020-27-01
2. 2020-12-14
3. 2020-01-02
4. 11-10-12

In examples #1 & #2 we can easily infer that date format. In example #1, The first four digit have to be the year (there's no 2020th month or 2020th day of a month), the following two digits have to be the day of the month (there's no 27th month and we already have year information) and the last two digits are the month (we already have year and day of month information). We can use a similar approach for example #2.

For example #3 is that the first day of the second month, or is that the second day of the first month? It's impossible to tell without more information. If for instances we had the following sequence of dates: '2020-22-01', '2020-25-01', **'2020-01-02'**, it would be reasonable to infer that '2020-01-02' refers to the first day of the second month, otherwise we would not be able to parse the previous two dates.

In example #4, it's impossible to infer the date format. Either pair of digits would make sense as a year, month or day. (Using pandas.read_csv() you can make use of the dayfirst and yearfirst kwargs, or explicitly declare your date formats and use `pandas.to_datetime(some_df, format=)`.

### Your problem

Your dates are ambiguous, from what you've included in your question is not possible to infer whether it's in a day first format (dd-mm) or a month first format (mm-dd). `pandas` defaults to `dayfirst=False` so a date like your date `2020-02-01` is expected to mean the second day of the first month *unless* you specific otherwise. [See pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

> dayfirst : *bool*, *default* False
>
> DD/MM format dates, international and European format.

Above means that in order to parse 01/02 (DD/MM), 2020/02/01 (iso/international format) or 01/02/2020 (European format) as the first day of the second month you will need to specify `pandas.read_csv(somefile.csv, ... dayfirst=True)`.

> I've tried several conversion functions from stackoverflow as well as other websites, but they either just don't work, or do nothing.

You haven't provided the code that you've used that didn't work, nor the code which you used which parsed your dates as month first. If you include an example of what you actually tried I can make a specific comment.

In your question you say that your date format is in (yyyy-mm-dd) but you passed `format='%m/%d/%Y'` and in your screenshots you have '/' and '-' as your separator in different places. So I'm not sure what your original dates look like.

What you passed to the `format` `kwarg` means the first two digits are zero-passed months (i.e 04) followed by a '/' then zero-padded days, followed by '/' and then year as yyyy. If what you wrote at the beginning of your question is correct you should have passed `format='%Y-%m-%d'` [(see the `strftime` format codes)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://towardsdatascience.com/4-tricks-you-should-know-to-parse-date-columns-with-pandas-read-csv-27355bb2ad0e

Essentially, try the dayfirst optional input for the read_csv function.
You would set it to True and have

```
collections_data = pd.read_csv('./monthly_collections.csv', dayfirst = True)
```

Comment: OP actually need the opposite `dayfirst = True`. `False` is the default option and the reason for OPs problem.

Comment: Ah whoops you are right I read it too fast.

Comment: This does nothing.

Comment: I actually put in dayFirst=True (which it is not) and now its working.

(PS this is why I am finding Python so frustrating. The functions/parameters in the documentation dont always do what they say they do).

Comment: With a capital F? Weird. Atleast you fixed it! Good luck with the rest

Comment: hahaha, I thought you meant something else for a moment.
Yes, I tries 'false', 'False' and 'FALSE' - I am using VSCode, so it corrects it to 'False' anyway, unless you override it.

Thnx though.

Comment: @GenDemo The functions and documentation always do as they say...not necessarily what the programmers wants. If something's not working it's normally due to not understanding. I'll write an answer to explain what's happening in your specific example.

Comment: @GenDemo Also your dates as you describe them in your question are actually in a dayfirst format. dayfirst is a technical term in this case and doesn't mean the same as in natural language, see my answer more detail.